# Ping Pong - OutofRange Exception

Tags: c#, exception, pong

I created this Ping Pong game against a computer but I have a problem. Everything works fine but whenever the ball touches one of the walls it shows me out of range error, even though I have set it so it can't exit the console. The problem only happens on two of the walls and the others work fine! I also have a score system, and I can't check if it works if I don't fix that problem.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;

namespace Ping_Pong
{
    class Program
    {
        static int firstplayerpadsize = 4;
        static int secondplayerpadsize = 4;
        static int ballpositionx = 0;
        static int ballpositiony = 0;
        static bool balldirectionup = true;
        static bool balldirectionright = false;
        static int firstplayerposition = 0;
        static int secondplayerposition = 0;
        static int firstplayerresult = 0;
        static int secondplayerresult = 0;
        static Random randomGenerator = new Random();

        static void RemoveScrollbars()
        {
             Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
             Console.BufferHeight = Console.WindowHeight;
             Console.BufferWidth = Console.WindowWidth;
        }

        static void DrawFirstPlayer()
        {
            for (int y = firstplayerposition; y < firstplayerposition + firstplayerpadsize; y++)
            {
                PrintAtPosition(0, y, '|');
                PrintAtPosition(1, y, '|');
            }
        }

        static void PrintAtPosition(int x, int y, char symbol)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y);
            Console.Write(symbol);
        }

        static void DrawSecondPlayer()
        {
            for (int y = secondplayerposition; y < secondplayerposition + secondplayerpadsize; y++)
            {
                PrintAtPosition(Console.WindowWidth - 1, y, '|');
                PrintAtPosition(Console.WindowWidth - 2, y, '|');
            }
        }

        static void SetInitialsPoints()
        {
            firstplayerposition = Console.WindowHeight / 2 - firstplayerpadsize / 2;
            secondplayerposition = Console.WindowHeight / 2 - secondplayerpadsize / 2;
            SetBall();
        }

        static void SetBall()
        {
            ballpositionx = Console.WindowWidth / 2;
            ballpositiony = Console.WindowHeight / 2;
        }

        static void DrawBall()
        {
            PrintAtPosition(ballpositionx, ballpositiony, '@');
        }

        static void PrintResult()
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(Console.WindowWidth / 2 - 1, 0);
            Console.WriteLine("{0}-{1}", firstplayerresult, secondplayerresult);
        }

        static void MoveFirstPlayerDown()
        {
            if (firstplayerposition < Console.WindowHeight - firstplayerpadsize)
            {
                firstplayerposition++;
            }
        }

        static void MoveFirstPlayerUp()
        {
            if (firstplayerposition > 0)
            {
                firstplayerposition--;
            }
        }

        static void MoveSecondPlayerDown()
        {
            if (secondplayerposition < Console.WindowHeight - secondplayerpadsize)
            {
                secondplayerposition++;
            }
        }

        static void MoveSecondPlayerUp()
        {
            if (secondplayerposition > 0)
            {
                secondplayerposition--;
            }
        }

        static void SecondPlayerAIMove()
    {
        //int randomNumber = randomGenerator.Next(0, 2);
        //    if (randomNumber == 0)
        //    {
        //        MoveSecondPlayerUp();
        //    }
        //    if (randomNumber == 1)
        //    {
        //        MoveSecondPlayerDown();
        //    }

       // if (randomNumber == 0)
       // {
            if (balldirectionup == true)
            {
                MoveSecondPlayerUp();
            }
            else
            {
                MoveSecondPlayerDown();
            }
        }
   // }

        static void MoveBall()
        {
            if (ballpositiony == 0)
            {
                balldirectionup = false;
            }
            if (ballpositiony == Console.WindowHeight - 1)
            {
                balldirectionup = true;
            }
            if (ballpositionx == Console.WindowWidth - 1)
            {
                SetBall();
                balldirectionright = false;
                balldirectionup = true;
                firstplayerresult++;
                Console.SetCursorPosition(Console.WindowHeight / 2, Console.WindowWidth / 2);
                Console.WriteLine("Score for player 1.");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            if (ballpositionx == 0)
            {
                SetBall();
                balldirectionright = true;
                balldirectionup = true;
                secondplayerresult++;
                Console.SetCursorPosition(Console.WindowHeight / 2, Console.WindowWidth / 2);
                Console.WriteLine("Score for player 2.");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }

            if (ballpositionx < 3)
            {
                if (ballpositiony >= firstplayerposition && ballpositiony < firstplayerposition 
                   + firstplayerpadsize)
                {
                    balldirectionright = true;
                }
            }


            if (ballpositionx >= Console.WindowWidth - 3 - 1)
            {
                if (ballpositiony >= secondplayerposition && ballpositiony < secondplayerposition + secondplayerpadsize)
                {
                    balldirectionright = false;
                }
            }
            if (balldirectionup)
            {
                ballpositiony--;
            }
            else
            {
                ballpositiony++;
            }

            if (balldirectionright)
            {
                ballpositionx++;
            }
            else
            {
                ballpositionx--;
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            RemoveScrollbars();
            SetInitialsPoints();
            while (true)
            {
                if (Console.KeyAvailable)
                {
                    ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo = Console.ReadKey();
                    if (keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow)
                    {
                        MoveFirstPlayerUp();
                    }
                    if (keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.DownArrow)
                    {
                        MoveFirstPlayerDown();
                    }
                }
                SecondPlayerAIMove();
                MoveBall();
                Console.Clear();
                DrawFirstPlayer();
                DrawSecondPlayer();
                DrawBall();
                PrintResult();
                Thread.Sleep(60);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the exact error and which method does it occur in?

Comment: Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: The value must be great
er than or equal to zero and less than the console's buffer size in that dimensi
on.
Parameter name: top
Actual value was 40.
   at System.Console.SetCursorPosition(Int32 left, Int32 top)
   at Ping_Pong.Program.MoveBall() in c:\Users\PC\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\P
rojects\Ping Pong\Ping Pong\Program.cs:line 162
   at Ping_Pong.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\PC\Documents\Visual Stud
io 2013\Projects\Ping Pong\Ping Pong\Program.cs:line 223

^ Exact error, copied after it occured. Thank you Nate W.

Comment: Copied the code, executed it, and started playing :). Forgot all about the exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the method `MoveBall`, you have the SetCursorPosition arguments inverted.
The first one is the distance from the left border and the second one the distance from the top border.

```
Console.SetCursorPosition(Console.WindowWidth / 2, Console.WindowHeight / 2);
```

This causes the error because the max value for the y value is 24 and you pass 40.